# How to read data from binary files properly in C++ till the last data?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, eof

I recently learnt that to read properly from a text file we use

```
while(file>>var1>>var2){
   //do stuff with data
}
```

instead of

```
while(file){
   file>>var1>>var2;
   //do stuff with data
}
```

because the latter performs one extra read even after last data item is read and on the next read it is able to read the `eof`, so if we have something like `std::vector<CLASSNAME>CLASSVECTOR`, we end up having one extra entry in the vector, while if we use the first method it reads only till the last record.

My question is if how do I read till the last record in case of a binary file?
So if I have something like:

```
class class1 {
   int a;
   class2 obj2;
   class3 obj3;
public:
   void write_ binary(std::ofstream file) const;
   void read_file(std::ifstream file);
   //rest of class definition
};
```

And I write this class like so :

```
void class1::write_ binary(std::ofstream file) const {
   file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a),sizeof(a));
   obj2.write_binary(file); //this writes the data in the same way using 
   reinterpret_cast to ofstream file
   obj3.write_binary(file); //this writes the data in the same way using 
   reinterpret_cast to ofstream file
}
```

And also if I read the file like so :

```
void class1::read_file(std::ifstream file) {
   file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a),sizeof(a));
   obj2.read_binary(file); //this reads data for obj2 in the same way using 
   read() and reinterpret_cast
   obj3.read_binary(file); //this reads data for obj3 in the same way using read() and reinterpret_cast
}
```

And if I want to store this data in a vector like so:

```
class1 obj1;
std::vector<class1>records;

while(file)
{
   obj1.read_binary(file);
   records.push_back(obj1);
   //reset obj1 to initial state
}
```

I end up getting an extra record in `vector records`. I cannot use `while(file>>obj1)` since I want to use `>>` for `cin`.
Please explain how do I read from binary file without reading an extra record.

Comment: If you want to read binary data, then [_text formatted extraction_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) using `>>` is probably a bad idea. Take a look at [`std::istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead.

Comment: In actual program I'm not using `>>` at all.

Comment: I just say because you mentioned it. Anyways, post a [mcve] as required here, which reproduces your problem please. You know this is required when posting here.#

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as your text example, the test on the `file` must be **after** the read not before.

```
for (;;)
{
     obj1.read_binary(file);
     if (!file) // did the previous read fail?
         break; // if so quit the loop
     records.push_back(obj1);
}
```